# space behind unit in nomenclature list

Tags: nomenclature

I would like to have the unit closer to the symbol description in my nomenclature list. But when I use the command from the help file and add a space after the unit:

```
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}[#1]\hspace{2cm}}}
```

only the last entry is moved. How can I move all entries by 2cm to the left?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}[#1]\hspace{2cm}}}


\nomenclature[C]{$  m   $}{ mass    \nomunit{$\si{  kg  }$}}
\nomenclature[C]{$  \omega\_{m} $}{ mechanical angular frequency    \nomunit{$\si{  Hz  }$}}
\nomenclature[C]{$  \omega\_{el}    $}{ electrical angular frequency    \nomunit{$\si{  Hz  }$}}

Here comes the nomenclature:

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces are gobbled when they are at a line break; add `\mbox{}` after the `\hspace{2cm}`; I actually used `\hspace*` and `\nolinebreak` to ensure this space is not used for a line break in any case.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}[#1]\nolinebreak\hspace*{2cm}\mbox{}}%
}


\nomenclature[C]{$m$}{mass \nomunit{$\si{kg}$}}
\nomenclature[C]{$\omega_{\mathrm{m}}$}{mechanical angular frequency \nomunit{$\si{Hz}$}}
\nomenclature[C]{$\omega_{\mathrm{el}}$}{electrical angular frequency \nomunit{$\si{Hz}$}}

Here comes the nomenclature:

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also the fixes to the symbols.