# List of symbols - last entry in the output has the unit column shifted right

Tags: spacing, nomenclature, nomencl

[image: Last two entries of the list of symbols]

The attached image shows the last two entries in the list of symbols in the pdf output.
I used the code:

```
\nomenclature{X, Y, Z}{Forces along X, Y and Z axes  \nomunit{\si{\newton}}}

\usepackage[intoc, english]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\nomlabelwidth=30mm
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

Package was introduced as above and printed as

```
\printnomenclature
```

Everything else seems ok except the unit of the last entry is shifted left. Is there a way to correct this? Thank you!

Comment: Did you get your code from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167482/47927 ? If yes, change `\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}[#1]\hspace{2cm}}}` to `\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}[#1]}}`.

Comment: I guess so  the modification worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, I hope you understand now why you should always provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). It was just by chance, that I found this piece of code, because I looked up the macro `\nomunit` that is obviously a custom macro. Had I not found it, nobody would have been able to help you with just the few lines of code you provided.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: I made an answer from the comments, in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, I assume that you probably copied your code from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167482/47927). At least it is the first thing I find if I run a search for "`\nomunit`" which is obviously not a macro provided by the `nomencl` package. Note that in the linked question, this macro doesn't work as intended either.

Anyways, you should delete the `\hspace{2cm}` from the definition of the macro `\nomunit`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[intoc, english]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\nomlabelwidth=30mm
\usepackage{siunitx}

% \newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}[#1]\hspace{2cm}}}
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}[#1]}} % <- remove `\hspace{2cm}` here

\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\nomenclature{V}{Kinematic velocity \nomunit{\si[per-mode = symbol]{\metre\per\second}}}
\nomenclature{X, Y, Z}{Forces along X, Y and Z axes  \nomunit{\si{\newton}}}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

The output should then be as follows:

[image]